# How can I expand the 5V pins?

Tags: gpio, power-supply

I require 2 more 5v pins to be used - as I would like to avoid welding the 4 wires directly to the 5V pins, I wanted to know if it would be possible to expand those pins.

I would require a small board, something that could easily be added to the raspberry box.

Does that exist?

Comment: I would strongly advise against "welding" anything near, or to, any part of a Raspberry Pi. Only damage can result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called a breadboard.  They come in a variety of sizes.

Comment: Thanks @joan! Can you show an example / schema about how that would be setup? So I can mark the answer